# Accuracy of accept_language to detect country

Tags: http, geolocation, http-accept-language

I need to detect the country of users but I'm trying to avoid the whole call to an external service to get the location based on IP or to an internal database. I need to make this service really responsive and it takes almost half a second to query any external service so I'm trying to avoid that. Also any call to a db would be costly for this approach. I need the page to respond in less than 20ms.

I'm thinking of get the country locale based on `Accept_language` header.

My question is. Does anyone know how accurate may this be? I'm aware country is not always present or users may change default language or be present on a different country with their computers.

Does anyone had previous experience or is there any documentation (I couldn't find one googling or in w3 page) that specifies a percent of accuracy or error using this approach?

Comment: Language ⇏ country. Read [Accept-Language used for locale setting](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales).

Comment: Already read it. I'm asking for % accuracy of accept-language method as locale. Not implying that will always work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Detecting the users country by it language settings is just a **bad** and **stupid** idea. I am from Germany and I know a lot of people who use their browser/mobile phone or OS in an other language then German. There are a few delivery services I know which check for the language transmitted by the browser and do not work if it isn't German. Guess where I order never again.
- Simple detect the language by their IP. There a few (even free) services available which would convert IP into a country.
  For example: http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite. They do have a web API, a server you could install or just grab the whole database and implement it on your own. Also, there are plenty of modules/helpers for various web servers, which won't require any extensive coding. (See: http://www.maxmind.com/app/mod_geoip for Apache, this embeds the country of the visitor as a HTTP Header.)
  The DB results are cached and should be fast enough for you needs. 20ms is very fast, if you think about all the time is wasted for the packages to get to your server and then whole back ;-)

Comment: Using browser language is an extremely simple implementation, carries no cost, and does not require regular updates. IP detection can also be completely off, especially the "light" Maxmind databases are made inaccurate on purpose, so when they are off, you're lucky if it stays on the same continent. Many German mobile IPs register in Russia. ;-) I found this page looking for some hard statistics as I feel the country part of the browser language might work well enough for things like preselecting countries in forms, where the user can still correct errors.

Answer (score 2):

I only can recommend you use a local DB. I have used the following free database since 5 or more years. Just download the zip. Maybe you will need transform cvs to mysql data before load your DB but it's easy to do.

http://ip-to-country.webhosting.info/node/view/6

It is regularly updated. And it is more accurate than any server/browser configuration.

A php based guide to use it in http://ip-to-country.webhosting.info/node/view/118. It's very easy!

**EDIT**: OK, I just seen (Last updated on December 14 2010). Is up to you...

Comment: You're right that's a better approach. Yet still I was thinking to avoid a call to a db. That would require more hardware and so more costs that is what i'm trying to avoid this since it's a lot of traffic (several millions/day).

Answer (score 2):

User @TheHippo is totally right. Using the `Accept-Language` HTTP info is really unreliable to get the user's country. Though, it has little advantages like speed, since it is not dependent on external services to track country from IP. You can try to use it, as a backend service, when the geoIP-type services are unavailable or when they provide you with a country in which your site doesn't render or users doesn't serve.

I use this function as a backend service, when the result from geoIP-type services do not satisfy. For this purpose check also the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language).

```js
//accept_language may be for example "pt"  or "pt-PT" or    
//"pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,de-DE;q=0.6,de;q=0.5,fr-FR;q=0.4,fr;q=0.3,es;q=0.2"
var getCountryFromHTTP = function (accept_language){

    var CC; //Country Code

    //in some cases like "fr" or "hu" the language and the country codes are the same
    if (accept_language.length === 2){
        CC = accept_language.toUpperCase(); 
    }
    //get "PT" out of "pt-PT"
    else if (accept_language.length === 5){          
        CC = accept_language.substring(3, 5); 
    }
    //ex: "pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,de-DE;q=0.6,de;q=0.5,fr-FR;q=0.4,fr;q=0.3,es;q=0.2"
    //gets the first two capial letters that fit into 2-letter ISO country code
    else if (accept_language.length > 5) {
        var substr;
        for (var i=0; i+2<accept_language.length; i++){
            substr = accept_language.substring(i, i+2);
            if (isoCountries.hasOwnProperty(substr)){
                return substr;
            }            
        }
    }

    if (isoCountries.hasOwnProperty(CC)){
        return CC;
    }

    return false;
};

//2-letter ISO Country Codes
var isoCountries = {
    'AF' : 'Afghanistan',
    'AX' : 'Aland Islands',
    'AL' : 'Albania',
    'DZ' : 'Algeria',
    'AS' : 'American Samoa',
    'AD' : 'Andorra',
    'AO' : 'Angola',
    'AI' : 'Anguilla',
    'AQ' : 'Antarctica',
    'AG' : 'Antigua And Barbuda',
    'AR' : 'Argentina',
    'AM' : 'Armenia',
    'AW' : 'Aruba',
    'AU' : 'Australia',
    'AT' : 'Austria',
    'AZ' : 'Azerbaijan',
    'BS' : 'Bahamas',
    'BH' : 'Bahrain',
    'BD' : 'Bangladesh',
    'BB' : 'Barbados',
    'BY' : 'Belarus',
    'BE' : 'Belgium',
    'BZ' : 'Belize',
    'BJ' : 'Benin',
    'BM' : 'Bermuda',
    'BT' : 'Bhutan',
    'BO' : 'Bolivia',
    'BA' : 'Bosnia And Herzegovina',
    'BW' : 'Botswana',
    'BV' : 'Bouvet Island',
    'BR' : 'Brazil',
    'IO' : 'British Indian Ocean Territory',
    'BN' : 'Brunei Darussalam',
    'BG' : 'Bulgaria',
    'BF' : 'Burkina Faso',
    'BI' : 'Burundi',
    'KH' : 'Cambodia',
    'CM' : 'Cameroon',
    'CA' : 'Canada',
    'CV' : 'Cape Verde',
    'KY' : 'Cayman Islands',
    'CF' : 'Central African Republic',
    'TD' : 'Chad',
    'CL' : 'Chile',
    'CN' : 'China',
    'CX' : 'Christmas Island',
    'CC' : 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands',
    'CO' : 'Colombia',
    'KM' : 'Comoros',
    'CG' : 'Congo',
    'CD' : 'Congo, Democratic Republic',
    'CK' : 'Cook Islands',
    'CR' : 'Costa Rica',
    'CI' : 'Cote D\'Ivoire',
    'HR' : 'Croatia',
    'CU' : 'Cuba',
    'CY' : 'Cyprus',
    'CZ' : 'Czech Republic',
    'DK' : 'Denmark',
    'DJ' : 'Djibouti',
    'DM' : 'Dominica',
    'DO' : 'Dominican Republic',
    'EC' : 'Ecuador',
    'EG' : 'Egypt',
    'SV' : 'El Salvador',
    'GQ' : 'Equatorial Guinea',
    'ER' : 'Eritrea',
    'EE' : 'Estonia',
    'ET' : 'Ethiopia',
    'FK' : 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)',
    'FO' : 'Faroe Islands',
    'FJ' : 'Fiji',
    'FI' : 'Finland',
    'FR' : 'France',
    'GF' : 'French Guiana',
    'PF' : 'French Polynesia',
    'TF' : 'French Southern Territories',
    'GA' : 'Gabon',
    'GM' : 'Gambia',
    'GE' : 'Georgia',
    'DE' : 'Germany',
    'GH' : 'Ghana',
    'GI' : 'Gibraltar',
    'GR' : 'Greece',
    'GL' : 'Greenland',
    'GD' : 'Grenada',
    'GP' : 'Guadeloupe',
    'GU' : 'Guam',
    'GT' : 'Guatemala',
    'GG' : 'Guernsey',
    'GN' : 'Guinea',
    'GW' : 'Guinea-Bissau',
    'GY' : 'Guyana',
    'HT' : 'Haiti',
    'HM' : 'Heard Island & Mcdonald Islands',
    'VA' : 'Holy See (Vatican City State)',
    'HN' : 'Honduras',
    'HK' : 'Hong Kong',
    'HU' : 'Hungary',
    'IS' : 'Iceland',
    'IN' : 'India',
    'ID' : 'Indonesia',
    'IR' : 'Iran, Islamic Republic Of',
    'IQ' : 'Iraq',
    'IE' : 'Ireland',
    'IM' : 'Isle Of Man',
    'IL' : 'Israel',
    'IT' : 'Italy',
    'JM' : 'Jamaica',
    'JP' : 'Japan',
    'JE' : 'Jersey',
    'JO' : 'Jordan',
    'KZ' : 'Kazakhstan',
    'KE' : 'Kenya',
    'KI' : 'Kiribati',
    'KR' : 'Korea',
    'KW' : 'Kuwait',
    'KG' : 'Kyrgyzstan',
    'LA' : 'Lao People\'s Democratic Republic',
    'LV' : 'Latvia',
    'LB' : 'Lebanon',
    'LS' : 'Lesotho',
    'LR' : 'Liberia',
    'LY' : 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya',
    'LI' : 'Liechtenstein',
    'LT' : 'Lithuania',
    'LU' : 'Luxembourg',
    'MO' : 'Macao',
    'MK' : 'Macedonia',
    'MG' : 'Madagascar',
    'MW' : 'Malawi',
    'MY' : 'Malaysia',
    'MV' : 'Maldives',
    'ML' : 'Mali',
    'MT' : 'Malta',
    'MH' : 'Marshall Islands',
    'MQ' : 'Martinique',
    'MR' : 'Mauritania',
    'MU' : 'Mauritius',
    'YT' : 'Mayotte',
    'MX' : 'Mexico',
    'FM' : 'Micronesia, Federated States Of',
    'MD' : 'Moldova',
    'MC' : 'Monaco',
    'MN' : 'Mongolia',
    'ME' : 'Montenegro',
    'MS' : 'Montserrat',
    'MA' : 'Morocco',
    'MZ' : 'Mozambique',
    'MM' : 'Myanmar',
    'NA' : 'Namibia',
    'NR' : 'Nauru',
    'NP' : 'Nepal',
    'NL' : 'Netherlands',
    'AN' : 'Netherlands Antilles',
    'NC' : 'New Caledonia',
    'NZ' : 'New Zealand',
    'NI' : 'Nicaragua',
    'NE' : 'Niger',
    'NG' : 'Nigeria',
    'NU' : 'Niue',
    'NF' : 'Norfolk Island',
    'MP' : 'Northern Mariana Islands',
    'NO' : 'Norway',
    'OM' : 'Oman',
    'PK' : 'Pakistan',
    'PW' : 'Palau',
    'PS' : 'Palestinian Territory, Occupied',
    'PA' : 'Panama',
    'PG' : 'Papua New Guinea',
    'PY' : 'Paraguay',
    'PE' : 'Peru',
    'PH' : 'Philippines',
    'PN' : 'Pitcairn',
    'PL' : 'Poland',
    'PT' : 'Portugal',
    'PR' : 'Puerto Rico',
    'QA' : 'Qatar',
    'RE' : 'Reunion',
    'RO' : 'Romania',
    'RU' : 'Russian Federation',
    'RW' : 'Rwanda',
    'BL' : 'Saint Barthelemy',
    'SH' : 'Saint Helena',
    'KN' : 'Saint Kitts And Nevis',
    'LC' : 'Saint Lucia',
    'MF' : 'Saint Martin',
    'PM' : 'Saint Pierre And Miquelon',
    'VC' : 'Saint Vincent And Grenadines',
    'WS' : 'Samoa',
    'SM' : 'San Marino',
    'ST' : 'Sao Tome And Principe',
    'SA' : 'Saudi Arabia',
    'SN' : 'Senegal',
    'RS' : 'Serbia',
    'SC' : 'Seychelles',
    'SL' : 'Sierra Leone',
    'SG' : 'Singapore',
    'SK' : 'Slovakia',
    'SI' : 'Slovenia',
    'SB' : 'Solomon Islands',
    'SO' : 'Somalia',
    'ZA' : 'South Africa',
    'GS' : 'South Georgia And Sandwich Isl.',
    'ES' : 'Spain',
    'LK' : 'Sri Lanka',
    'SD' : 'Sudan',
    'SR' : 'Suriname',
    'SJ' : 'Svalbard And Jan Mayen',
    'SZ' : 'Swaziland',
    'SE' : 'Sweden',
    'CH' : 'Switzerland',
    'SY' : 'Syrian Arab Republic',
    'TW' : 'Taiwan',
    'TJ' : 'Tajikistan',
    'TZ' : 'Tanzania',
    'TH' : 'Thailand',
    'TL' : 'Timor-Leste',
    'TG' : 'Togo',
    'TK' : 'Tokelau',
    'TO' : 'Tonga',
    'TT' : 'Trinidad And Tobago',
    'TN' : 'Tunisia',
    'TR' : 'Turkey',
    'TM' : 'Turkmenistan',
    'TC' : 'Turks And Caicos Islands',
    'TV' : 'Tuvalu',
    'UG' : 'Uganda',
    'UA' : 'Ukraine',
    'AE' : 'United Arab Emirates',
    'GB' : 'United Kingdom',
    'US' : 'United States',
    'UM' : 'United States Outlying Islands',
    'UY' : 'Uruguay',
    'UZ' : 'Uzbekistan',
    'VU' : 'Vanuatu',
    'VE' : 'Venezuela',
    'VN' : 'Viet Nam',
    'VG' : 'Virgin Islands, British',
    'VI' : 'Virgin Islands, U.S.',
    'WF' : 'Wallis And Futuna',
    'EH' : 'Western Sahara',
    'YE' : 'Yemen',
    'ZM' : 'Zambia',
    'ZW' : 'Zimbabwe'
};

console.log(getCountryFromHTTP("fr"));
console.log(getCountryFromHTTP("pt-BR"));
console.log(getCountryFromHTTP("pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7"));
console.log(getCountryFromHTTP("pt;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7"));
```